# problems with my node js code to store input in postgresql database

Tags: html, node.js, database, postgresql

Using nodejs, i am trying to store the text that i type in my  input area of my html page  in a postgresql database. In other words :  when i write in the input areas input1 and input2, when i click on the "OK" button, i want input1 to be stored in column"id-utilisateur" and input2  to be stored in column "interviewed-named" of the table"questionnaire". then when the data is sotred in that table, i want to be redirected to an url " that says " succesfully stored"

the html code for the input area is the following:

```
<div class="inner-container">
        <div class="left">
            <p>Label Form : </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Label "/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="left">
            <p>interviewed person name : </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="name "/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button-container">
        <form action="/OK" method="post">
            <button type="submit">OK</button>
          </form>
    </div>
```

the code in my app.js file is the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { Client } = require('pg');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Création-form.html');
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');

})


const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'adalie'
});

client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
    }
});
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/OK', (req, res) => {
  const client = new Client();
  client.connect();

  const id_utilisateur = req.body.id_utilisateur;
  const interviewed_named = req.body.interviewed_named;

  const query = 'INSERT INTO questionnaire (id_utilisateur, interviewed_named) VALUES ($1, $2)';
  const values = [id_utilisateur, interviewed_named];

  client.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
    client.end();
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      res.status(500).send('Error while saving data to the database');
    } else {
      res.redirect('https://example.com/');
    }
  });
});
```

i can't seem to figure out where the problem is or where did i go wrong with my code

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem.

Comment: Your inputs aren’t in the form, and they’re named differently from how you try to access them on the server side. Please consider using some logging or a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

try to move `<input>` tags inside `<form>` tag and add `name` attribute for inputs, like that:

```
<form action='/OK' method='post'>
  <div class='inner-container'>
    <div class='left'>
      <p>Label Form :</p>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
      <input id='input1' type='text' placeholder='Label ' name='id_utilisateur' />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-container'>
    <div class='left'>
      <p>interviewed person name :</p>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
      <input id='input2' type='text' placeholder='name ' name='interviewed_named' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='button-container'>
    <button type='submit'>OK</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i did but when i click on the ok button i get the following error:        C:\Users\Asus_user\Desktop\Adalie\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:24
    throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')
    ^
Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

Comment: I also get the following error on the page when i click on ok: Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.